# How do I convert this into Win Forms with a button click?

Tags: program-entry-point, itext7

```
namespace iText.Samples.Sandbox.Tables
{
    public class SimpleTable
    {
        public static readonly string DEST = "results/sandbox/tables/simple_table.pdf";

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
             FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
             file.Directory.Create();

             new SimpleTable().ManipulatePdf(DEST);
        }

        private void ManipulatePdf(String dest)
        {
             PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
             Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

             Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(8)).UseAllAvailableWidth();

             for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
             {
                 table.AddCell("hi");
             }

             doc.Add(table);

             doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

It my seem easy for most, but I have tried and tried and am just stumped. It is not just a console app, and it is not just a class. I am missing something simple I am sure but I am not trying to do a command line app either where I pass arguments to this app. Please help.

Tried all I could.

I have done plenty of forms apps and a few console apps, but I know I am missing something very simple.

I have looked and don't see my answer.

Comment: How do I do this without using Main as the entry point, but instead using the form name and InitializeComponent();

Comment: The error I get is "can't have multiple entry points"

Comment: I also get 'PdfWriter' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments. Is it just not fully qualifing PdfWriter? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole class into your project.

Change the **Main** method name to something else.

You could remove the parameter of the **Main** method.

Call `SimpleTable.methodName()` in the `ButtonClick` method.

That should do it.